# How to split 8 byte string into 2 byte chunks

Tags: php, hex

$hexValue = "11503B58";

I want to get output:

```
Seed0 = 0x11
Seed1 = 0x50
Seed2 = 0x3B
Seed3 = 0x58
```

Seed0 ~ Seed3 should be also Hex value (not string).

Answer (score 0):

A simple quick and dirty way is converting it to a string and then split it.

You can convert a hex *value* into hex *representation string*.

```
var_dump(dechex(0x11503B58));
```

```
string(8) "11503b58"
```

**The internal representation is always decimal.**

```
var_dump(0x11503B58)
```

```
int(290470744)
```

```
$hexValue = '11503B58';
preg_match_all('/../', $hexValue, $matches);
[$seed0, $seed1, $seed2, $seed3] = array_map('hexdec', $matches[0]);
[$seeda, $seedb, $seedc, $seedd] = array_map(fn($v) => '0x' . strtoupper($v), $matches[0]);

echo $seed0, ' : ', $seeda, PHP_EOL;
echo $seed1, ' : ', $seedb, PHP_EOL;
echo $seed2, ' : ', $seedc, PHP_EOL;
echo $seed3, ' : ', $seedd, PHP_EOL;
```

```
17 : 0x11
80 : 0x50
59 : 0x3B
88 : 0x58
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to accomplish this using [bitwise operations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) instead of string parsing.

```php
<?php
$hexValue = "11503B58";

// convert the string to a native integer
$int = hexdec($hexValue);

// use bitwise operations to select the bits you're interested in
$seed0 = ($int >> 24) & 0xFF;
$seed1 = ($int >> 16) & 0xFF;
$seed2 = ($int >>  8) & 0xFF;
$seed3 = $int & 0xFF;

// at this point the values in $seed0..3 are the integer values
// you can now format them as you need them, for example:

printf("Seed0 = int %d, hex 0x%x\n", $seed0, $seed0);
printf("Seed1 = int %d, hex 0x%x\n", $seed1, $seed1);
printf("Seed2 = int %d, hex 0x%x\n", $seed2, $seed2);
printf("Seed3 = int %d, hex 0x%x\n", $seed3, $seed3);
?>
```

The result is:

```
Seed0 = int 17, hex 0x11
Seed1 = int 80, hex 0x50
Seed2 = int 59, hex 0x3b
Seed3 = int 88, hex 0x58
```

This is much faster then all other methods so far proposed that make use of arrays and is immune to issues where your input value may be a smaller number that doesn't actually consist of 4 bytes.

You could also do this in a loop, storing the result in an array:

```php
<?php
$hexValue = "11503B58";
$int = hexdec($hexValue);

$values = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i, $int >>= 8)
  array_unshift($values, $int & 0xFF);

print_r($values);
?>
```

Result (note, printing in base 10, apply formatting if you want the hex representation):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17
    [1] => 80
    [2] => 59
    [3] => 88
)
```

Alternatively if you want the variables AND the loop to avoid duplicated code, you can do the following

```php
<?php
$hexValue = "11503B58";
$int = hexdec($hexValue);

for($i = 3; $i >= 0; --$i, $int >>= 8)
{
  $var  = "seed$i";
  $$var = $int & 0xFF;
}

printf("Seed0 = int %d, hex 0x%x\n", $seed0, $seed0);
printf("Seed1 = int %d, hex 0x%x\n", $seed1, $seed1);
printf("Seed2 = int %d, hex 0x%x\n", $seed2, $seed2);
printf("Seed3 = int %d, hex 0x%x\n", $seed3, $seed3);
?>
```

Do note however that this is all assuming your input will never exceed your architecture limits (usually 64-bit (16 bytes) with current hardware), if you need to perform the same action on a long data stream you should look at using [`unpack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
$hexValue = 0x11503B58;

$result = array_map(
  'hexdec',
  array_filter(
    explode(
      "\n",
      chunk_split(dechex($hexValue), 2)
    )
  )
);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17   // decimal equivalent of 0x11
    [1] => 80   // decimal equivalent of 0x50
    [2] => 59   // etc.
    [3] => 88   // 
)
```